# Attempting to scrape an "unscrapable" page?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm attempting to build a simple scraper, iterating through a website to pull two pieces of information and build myself a little reference list.

This is what the url looks like: "https://www.mtgstocks.com/prints/[[n]]"

The two pieces of information are the card name (Forbidden Alchemy) and card set (Innistrad).

Pretty straightforward, yeah? I thought so.

I attempted to pass any relevant anchors — css or xpath  — to try and isolate the two variables, but was met with "{xml_nodeset (0)}".

Here's the code that I ran:

```
# return page info
page_html <- read_html(httr::GET("https://www.mtgstocks.com/prints/1"))

# extract item name
page_html %>% 
  html_nodes("h3") %>%
  html_nodes("a") %>% 
  html_text()

# character(0)
```

I've scraped enough webpages to know that this information is being hidden, but I'm not exactly sure how. Would love help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are gathering the information from their API, which you can see in the network section of the developer tools. There is a ton of info of card that you can gather from that API - take a look.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr2)

get_card <- function(card_num) {
  cat("Scraping card num:", card_num, "\n") 
  data <- str_c("https://api.mtgstocks.com/prints/", card_num) %>%
    request() %>%
    req_perform() %>%
    resp_body_json(simplifyVector = TRUE) 

  tibble(
    name = data %>% 
      pluck("name"), 
    set = data %>% 
      pluck("card_set") %>% 
      pluck("name")
  )
}

get_card(1)

# A tibble: 1 × 2
  name              set      
  <chr>             <chr>    
1 Forbidden Alchemy Innistrad
```

Or get for a range of numbers. If the card does not exists, the code returns NA.

```
map_dfr(1:20, possibly(get_card, otherwise = tibble(
  name = NA_character_, 
  set = NA_character_
)))

# A tibble: 20 × 2
   name                 set      
   <chr>                <chr>    
 1 Forbidden Alchemy    Innistrad
 2 NA                   NA       
 3 Fortress Crab        Innistrad
 4 Frightful Delusion   Innistrad
 5 Full Moon's Rise     Innistrad
 6 Furor of the Bitten  Innistrad
 7 Gallows Warden       Innistrad
 8 Galvanic Juggernaut  Innistrad
 9 Garruk Relentless    Innistrad
10 Gatstaf Shepherd     Innistrad
11 Gavony Township      Innistrad
12 Geist of Saint Traft Innistrad
13 Geist-Honored Monk   Innistrad
14 Geistcatcher's Rig   Innistrad
15 Geistflame           Innistrad
16 Ghost Quarter        Innistrad
17 Ghostly Possession   Innistrad
18 Ghoulcaller's Bell   Innistrad
19 Ghoulcaller's Chant  Innistrad
20 Ghoulraiser          Innistrad
```